# Paypal Reference Transactions Webhook

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

We're currently looking into using Paypal's (Rest API) limited release "Reference Transactions": https://developer.paypal.com/docs/limited-release/reference-transactions/

After creating the billing agreement token, the user would be redirected to the approval URL to log in to Paypal. Approval should be done before the billing agreement is created.

Is there a webhook for the token approval that we can use to trigger the billing agreement creation?

We can use the "return url" or even check the status of the token manually to trigger the billing agreement creation but it would be simpler to use webhook if it's available.